# Image stride for MSpaint image in C# is +1 byte, why?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, byte, stride

I have a problem regarding some pixel-based operations in C#.
I wrote a class that serves as an image shell around a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e7y164x.aspx). It can give you the RGB values of a pixel at a certain (x,y) location in the image much faster than the `Bitmap.GetRGB(x,y)` color object by using [BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) and [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx) to get direct access to the image array and read the bytes from there. I added this function to get the RGB in an `0x00RRGGBB` mask at a (x,y) pixel.

```
public unsafe int getPixel(int x, int y)
    {
        byte* imgPointer = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
        int pixelPos = 0;
        if (y > 0) pixelPos += (y * bmpData.Stride);
        pixelPos += x * (hasAlpha ? 4 : 3);            

        int blue = *(imgPointer + pixelPos);
        int green = *(imgPointer + pixelPos + 1);
        int red = *(imgPointer + pixelPos + 2);

        int rgb = red << 16;
        rgb += green << 8;
        rgb += blue;

        return rgb;
    }
```

This works flawlessly for all the images I've worked with thus far, except for any image I generate using MSPaint. For example, I made a 5x1 image in paint containing 5 shades of yellow. When I load this image into my program however, the image stride is 16! I suspected it to be 15 (3 bytes per pixel, 5 pixels) but for some reason after the first three bytes (first pixel) there is an extra byte, and then the rest of the pixels follow in the array.

I have only found this for images that are saved by MSpaint and I was hoping anyone could explain me what that extra byte is for and how to detect that extra byte.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride.aspx):

`The stride is the width of a single row of pixels (a scan line), rounded up to a four-byte boundary. If the stride is positive, the bitmap is top-down. If the stride is negative, the bitmap is bottom-up.`

So stride is always a multiple of 4, and for your 3x5, will round up to 16.